# How to call a parent class method using child class reference using super keyword for object creation?

Tags: java

ClassA :

```
package assignment;

public class A {
public static void m1() {
    System.out.println("m1 method");
}
public void m2() {
    System.out.println("m2 method");
}

}
```

class B:

```
package assignment;

public class B extends A{
public static void m1() {
System.out.println("B class m1 method");
}
public void m2() {
System.out.println("B class m2 method");}}
```

How to use class A static method using class B?Is there any possible solution if any please suggest few ways.

Comment: You don't inherit static methods. There's the hint.

Comment: i have some doubt in calling m1 method of parent class using child class reference

Answer (score 0):

To call the method of the super class, the object should be of Super class. As :

```
A parent=new A();
parent.m1();
```

**Or**

Or you can override the super class function and call the Super.Function()

```
@Override
public void m1() {
    super.m1();

}
```